# Xamarin Forms How to set the min width of a label on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to achieve something that seems quite simple: Set the minimum width of a Label using a custom renderer in iOS. So far, I've tried this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(iOSLabelRenderer))]
namespace HopChild.CoreXamarin.iOS.Views
{
    public class iOSLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        private float MinWidth => (float)((CustomLabel)this.Element).MinWidth;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            this.SetMinWidth();
        }

        private void SetMinWidth()
        {
            this.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

            // Tried this:
            this.WidthAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(this.MinWidth).Active = true;

            // And this:
            this.Control.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            this.Control.WidthAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(this.MinWidth).Active = true;

            // And this:
            var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.Control, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, 1, this.MinWidth);
            constraint.Active = true;
            this.Control.AddConstraint(constraint);
        }
    }
}
```

But no matter what I do, there's always another width constraint that gets added later on (based on the label's content I think) that overrules my constraints.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this property doesn't work for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.minimumwidthrequest?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: It's strange. I have tried in local site, it seems that code about modfying size of Label can not work no matter in Renderer or Xaml.

Comment: @cahyo no the minimumWidthRequest in Xamarin doesn't work as you'd expect it. It's not the same as min-width in CSS for example.

Comment: @SimonCorcos What's the parent layout of your Label(it will be helpful if you post your xaml), there may be some constraint added by parent layout, e.g. when using StackLayout, if you add a label directly into a vertical stacklayout, with it's horizontaloptions default to 'Fill', the label will expand and fill the horizontal cell. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout#position-and-size-of-child-views).